# How to hide image if undefined with angular 6?

Tags: angular

I'm setting a code to show image only if data there..i need to hide if value is undefined..help Here...

```
<div class="column" *ngIf="idvisaurl">
<img width="100" height="100" [src] ="idvisaurl"> 
<div><h5 style="font:bold">Visa Photo</h5></div>
```

Comment: *i'm not getting result.?* What does that mean? Post all the relevant code, tell precisely what you expect to happen and what happens instead. A complete minimal example posted as a stackblitz would help, too.

Comment: Are you sure the value of idvisaurl is undefined?? is not empty string or null or anything else?? add {{ idvisaurl }} in html to test it

Comment: if it was an empty string or null, it would still be falsy and the div wouldn't show.

Comment: Your html is incorrect, it's missing the closing div

Comment: ya sure.. value is undefined @moha noorani

Comment: please add ts codes @LeoRoy

Comment: @LeoRoy Clear the question! In terms of expected output and current output

Answer (score 1):

Shared a reference code .... with dummy content

HTML:

```
<div  *ngIf="show != undefined">
   "CONTEMNTTT"
</div>

<div  *ngIf="notShow != undefined" >
   "CONTEMNTTT"
</div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  show = "show";
  notShow
}
```

[`Stackblitz_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-undefinedtest)